# Ошибка при обновлении ядра debian buster

Tags: debian, kernel

При очередном плановом обновлении пакетов получаю ошибку:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64 (4.19.67-2+deb10u2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
Error!  Build of xt_ACCOUNT.ko failed for: 4.19.0-6-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.6/build/ for more information.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
```

Хорошо. Смотрю /var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.6/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for xtables-addons-2.6 for kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64 (x86_64)
Thu 14 Nov 2019 11:52:12 AM MSK
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-6-amd64'
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-6-amd64 KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-    headers-4.19.0-6-common \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common/Makefile modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
...
```

Предложенный вариант `make oldconfig && make prepare` из каталога `/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.6/build`, поругался на отсутствие  `autoconf` и всё.

Само ядро обновилось и работает, но боюсь при перезагрузке может быть остановка.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой ошибки.

Comment: Извините, не понял смысл вашего комментария. С упомянутыми вами файлами всё в порядке, они на месте. Редактировать их вроде как не рекомендуется .

Comment: вы привели начало или конец файла `make.log`? если начало, то оно бесполезно. нужен конец — там и должна быть информация об ошибке.

Comment: Это было начало. Дальше ничего интересного я не увидел кроме этой строки: `/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.6/build/extensions/pknock/xt_pknock.c:116:19: error: field ‘desc’ has incomplete type`

Comment: Полный make.log здесь : https://gist.github.com/cc08/cf34779a9b921e3b9485cd4a6ce1971b

Comment: это и есть одна из ошибок. там их несколько — содержащих строку "error:". судя по смыслу ошибок — установленная у вас версия этих самых xtables-addons-чего-то-там не соответствует версии программы linux, для которой вы их компилируете. собственно, судя по версии программы linux, у вас, видимо, buster, а для этой версии дистрибутива нет пакетов xtables-addons-*: https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/xtables-addons-common https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/xtables-addons-dkms. так что разумнее будет удалить эти пакеты. а потом переконфигурировать пакет с программой linux.